Bitbucket shows non-existent changes as diff
I'm creating a PR on Bitbucket from branch A to branch B. Both branches have a cypress.config.ts file, and the files are identical. However, it shows a diff like the one below, which is confusing.

How can this be resolved?
Although I shouldn't see any differences, it shows the same files as diff.

Not unheard of. I've frequently seen faulty diff displays on Bitbucket (and also Gitlab and Azure Devops, to be fair). In doubt, check locally via terminal. Only way to be sure.

The diff shown in a PR is the diff from the merge base of the 2 branches to the head of the source branch, which is equivalent to git diff B...A instead of git diff B..A. It focuses on the changes that have been made since A has been forked from B. The merge-base of A and B is usually the latest common commit reachable from both. You can get the merge base by git merge-base A B.

The last common commits are indeed different, as you mentioned. So, how can I solve this issue? Is there a way to fix this @ElpieKay ?

@DreamifyApp I think it's working as designed, not an issue. An option is git switch A; git pull origin -r B; git push origin --force-with-lease A so that the merge base will be B. And then git diff B...A is equal to git diff B..A.

During this process, it reaches the rebase stage. Is there any way to skip this step directly? Because it suggests going through almost all the files one by one with --continue and making selections, but this will take a lot of time. I just want to see the difference in code lines between branches A and B on Bitbucket, independent of their histories. @ElpieKay

@DreamifyApp I'm not a Bitbucket user. Please check if the manual can help.
